# Blind casting with reflection for thread safe event call

Tags: c#, thread-safety, inversion-of-control, invoke

I am writing a class library that uses threading quite heavily and i would like to take thread safety into the library rather than having developers who us the code have to implement the thread safety themselves.

I have an event

```
public delegate void OnPostHandler();
public event OnPostHandler OnPost;
```

and a method

```
public void FireEvent() {
    Delegate[] delegate_list = OnPost.GetInvocationList();
    foreach (OnPostHandler d in delegate_list)
    {
       //detect if d.Target is a System.Windows.Forms.Control
       Type formType = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Control, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
       if(formType != null) {
           //need to cast d.Target to System.Windows.Forms.Control WITHOUT referencing System.Windows.Forms.Control
           if(d.Target.InvokeRequired) {
               d.Target.Invoke(d);
           } else {
               d();
           }
       } else {
           d();
       }
    }
}
```

within `FireEvent`, i would like to cast `d.Target` to a `System.Windows.Forms.Control` without `System.Windows.Forms.Control` being a specified cast within the code, i would like this done with the `formType` if possible so that i am not forced to link against the forms assembly myself as it is not a requirement of the library and should not have to be.

Alternatively, is there a better way of doing what i am attempting to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reflection you can:

```
Delegate[] delegate_list = OnPost.GetInvocationList();

Type formType = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Control, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
var invokeRequiredProp = formType.GetProperty("InvokeRequired");

foreach (OnPostHandler d in delegate_list)
{
    if(formType != null) {
        var invokeRequired = invokeRequiredProp.GetValue(d.Target, null);
        if (invokeRequired) {
            formType.GetMethod("Invoke").Invoke(d.Target, new object[]{d});
        } 
        else {
           d();
       }
    } else {
        d();
    }
}
```

`GetMethod` and `GetProperty` method may require `BindingFlags` arguments.

Without reflection you can use `ISynchronizeInvoke`

```
Delegate[] delegate_list = OnPost.GetInvocationList();

foreach (OnPostHandler d in delegate_list)
{
    var form = d.Target as ISynchronizeInvoke;
    if(form != null && form.InvokeRequired) {
      form.Invoke(d);
    } 
    else {
       d();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the interface [`ISynchronizeInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.aspx). It is in `System` and is implemented by `System.Windows.Forms.Control`.